# Inverse of a function $f_k(x) := f (x ⊕ k) ⊕ k$

Tags: block-cipher

$f : \{0, 1\}^4 → \{0, 1\}^4$

Given a function $f_k(x) := f (x ⊕ k) ⊕ k$, what is the inverse function $f_k^{-1}$?

I could not figure out how this would be done. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE! I hope that I correctly used $\TeX$ to format your question (click edit to see how that's done). $\;$ Hint: is what's asked always possible? Consider the case what $f(x)$ is zero for all $x$. Now, assume you know $f_k(x)$ and $k$, have access to $f$ or $f^{-1}$, and want $x$.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks a lot. I have looked at your edit suggestion and will do that from now on. 
About the question it is from one of the lab question. It has been bugging me for days. Probably the way Im thinking about inverse is not clear yet. Can you elaborate on you explanation abit further ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $f^{-1}$ exists (i.e., that $f$ is injective), then $$f_k^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(y \oplus k) \oplus k.$$ To see why consider an $x \in \{0,1\}^4$ so that $f_k(x) = y$. Then you have that $$y \oplus k = f (x \oplus k).$$ Now by applying $f^{-1}$ on both sides of that equation you have $$f^{-1}(y \oplus k) = x \oplus k.$$ And finally by XOR'ing $k$ on both sides you get the above result.

Comment: Thank you, you are a star ! 
Because $f^{-1}$ do exist so this work for me.

Comment: You are welcome. You should probably have stated that $f$ is injective in the question. Otherwise there is no solution, which, I think, is what fgrieu is hinting towards in his comment.

Comment: Im still new to crypto and English is not my first language, Thus still trying to figure out how exactly bijective and injective differ from one another. :)

Comment: @user3646249: bijective means that any element of the destination set has _exactly_ one way to be reached; that's _at most_ one way for [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), and _at least_ one way for surjective. A bijection is a bijective function, an injection is an injective function, a surjection is a surjective function.